# How to do this without double operators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I was trying to print some numbers within a certain range horizontally using for loop with double operators(+=)

```
str_1=''
for i in range(10): 
    str_1 += str(i)+" " 
print(str_1)
```

The output shows as :

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

How to print this output without double operators(+=)?

Comment: `str_1 = str_1 + str(i) + " "`?

Comment: @DanielHao it doesn't print horizontally.

Comment: @Niloy_Codes - the above posted is just to show one way to make `str` - `end=' '` has been pointed out earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @chepner in the comments solved my problem. Thanks to everyone for participating.

> str_1 = str_1 + str(i) + " "

Answer (score 4):

Use the `end` kwarg:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the join function

```
print(" ".join([str(i) for i in range(10)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write one line:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str,range(10)))
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'

# OR
>>> " ".join(map("{}".format, range(10)))
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```